# Javascript slice method, start at a certain word.s

Tags: javascript, html, string, slice

how do I make it so that my slice function starts at a certain word instead of just an integer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using `indexOf`, you can find the index of a word or letter and use that to offset as your `begin` parameter of `slice`

```js
// The string to analyze
const str = 'I am a super cool monkey man'

// The word to find
const word = 'cool'

// The result
console.log(str.slice(str.indexOf(word)))
```

Comment: I wonder why this get downvoted

Comment: Probably because its a duplicate...